# Transform a list of list architecture: [[1,2],[3,4]] -> [[1,3],[2,4]]

Tags: list, dart

How can I transform  `[[1,2],[3,4]]` into `[[1,3],[2,4]]` in Dart?

Comment: can you explain more about the logic?

Comment: The operation you are looking for is called "transpose"

Answer (score 2):

Your question should be detailled. You should generalize the logic behind.

In your specific case, a solution could be :

```
 const myList = [[1, 2],[3, 4]];
 final newList = [myList.map((e) => e.first).toList(), myList.map((e) => e.last).toList()];
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your question is to gather all the first elements of the list to a new list and all the last elements of the list into another list.

You could use the following code:

```
 const presentList = [[1, 2],[3, 4]];
 final updatedList = [presentList.map((e) => e.first).toList(), presentList.map((e) => e.last).toList()];
```

Now the content in the updatedList is `[[1,3][2,4]]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the general "transpose" operation, which takes a list of list of equal length, and creates a list of lists of the first, second, etc. elements, then:

```dart
List<List<T>> transpose<T>(List<List<T>> source) {
  if (source.isEmpty) return source;
  var length = source.first.length;
  // Maybe add check that all lists have same length.
  return [for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) 
    [for (var j = 0; j < source.length; j++) source[j][i]]];
}
```

If you care about validating the input, you can check that all the lists have the same length as `length`:

```dart
  for (var i = 1; i < source.length; i++) {
    if (source[i].length != length) {
      throw ArgumentError.value(source, "source", 
        "All lists must have same length");
    }
  }
```